# WinForm UI responds slowly during background thread is running

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I've designed a long-time process as below structure:

```
void OnButtonClick() {
    object initState = 0;

    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoLongTimeProcess));
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start(initState);
}

void DoLongTimeProcess(object initState) {
    // ... Do something
    InvokeAsyncMethod(CallbackFunction);
}

void CallbackFunction() {
    object newState = AnotherFunction(); // Don't care, just a function to create state

    // A 'if' logic to call function again, ex: if (newState is int)
    DoLongTimeProcess(newState);
}
```

My knowdledge, the thread has ended at `InvokeAsyncMethod` on the first call. Therefore, I cannot control priority of methods called later. I don't want to create another thread in `CallbackFunction` because it already belongs to another thread.

During above process is running, the UI seems slow to repond, for example, user want to cancel the process. How to make the UI response faster?

Comment: You should set the UI thread priority.

Comment: Please consider using the BackgroundWorker class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for dealing with background tasks in WinForms.

Comment: @mrida: I should let it default. Don't want my UI uses almost resource

Comment: @NikolaosGeorgiou: Could not use `BackgroundWorker` here because at the end of `DoLongTimeProcess`, it call a async method, so, the `BackgroundWorker` ends its task here, like my thread did.

Comment: Provide a simple SSCCE, please

Comment: As Nikolaos suggested, use the `BackgroundWorker`, in order to start another process at the end, you can use 2 `BackgroundWorker` components, utilize the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and initiate the other one.

Comment: @sallushan: As I mentioned in the question, I don't want to create another thread. I'm looking for other solutions.